# JQuery script not working in SP2013

Tags: 2013, jquery, attachments

I would like to show list of attachements in my flat view of discussion board in SP2013. Unfortunately i don't have access to SP Designer, so I was trying to use JQuery. But the script from this [site](http://bharatreddybasani.blogspot.com/2010/03/show-attachments-on-sharepoint.html), is not working on SP2013. Can anyone help me on this?

EDIT: I am using only first part of the script - without icons! I don't need them.

```
<script src="/.../Shared%20Documents/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("test");
        $('.ms-disc-padabove img[src*="attach.gif"]').each(function(index) {
            alert("test2");
            var divAttachments;
            var displayPageURL = $(this).parents().eq(2).next().find('a')[0].href;
            displayPageURL += " #idAttachmentsTable";
            if (index == 0) {
                divAttachments = "<br/><div id='divAttachments" + index + "'></div>";
                $($($($(this).parents('.ms-disc-padabove')[0]).parent().next()[0]).find('div')[1]).append($(divAttachments));
            } else {
                divAttachments = "<br/><div id='divAttachments" + index + "'></div>";
                $($($($(this).parents('.ms-disc-padabove')[0]).parent().next()[0]).find('div')[0]).append($(divAttachments));
            }
            $("#divAttachments" + index).load(displayPageURL);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you download a copy of the jQuery library used in the script and store it in the default library called "Documents"? That's what this line does. <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Shared Documents/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>

Comment: Yes, I did. And it is loaded. Just to see where is the problem I've added two alerts. But I can see "test" message but not "test2"

Comment: If it does not fire the second alert, then the script can't find the element. try to see if it triggers if you only have $('.ms-disc-padabove').

Answer (score 0):

Please use the this version of jQuery - **jquery-1.11.2.min**

The one mentioned in the site you provided uses version 1.4.2. You can download the latest version from [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js)

Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't change anything and it is still not working...:(